# How to retrieve value from json output

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud

I would like to retrieve transcript value from below shared output of console.log.But only that transcript value required which has another key is `confidence`.

**Output of console.log :**

```
  Data: {
    "results": [
    {
    "keywords_result": {
    "blocked": [
    {
    "normalized_text": "blocked",
    "start_time": 1.1,
    "confidence": 0.64,
    "end_time": 1.68
    }
    ]
    },
    "alternatives": [
    {
    "confidence": 0.81,
    "transcript": "your Name is Charlie "
    },
    {
    "transcript": "your Name is Charlie and "
    },
    {
    "transcript": "your Name is Charlies "
    }
    ],
    "final": true
    }
    ],
    "result_index": 0
    }
    Close: 1000
```

**Expected output:**

```
your Name is Charlie
```

Please note, I am expected value should be come from console.log output to a variable which I can use further.

Comment: Where is the output produced? What tools are you using or have at hand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Access nested values in JSON data using dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431641/javascript-access-nested-values-in-json-data-using-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
const confidenceObj = event.Data.results[0].alternatives.filter((ele)=>ele.confidence)
if(confidenceObj.length>0){console.log(confidenceObj[0].transcript);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code.

```js
var jsonData = {
    "results": [{
        "keywords_result": {
            "blocked": [{
                "normalized_text": "blocked",
                "start_time": 1.1,
                "confidence": 0.64,
                "end_time": 1.68
            }]
        },
        "alternatives": [{
                "confidence": 0.81,
                "transcript": "your Name is Charlie "
            },
            {
                "transcript": "your Name is Charlie and "
            },
            {
                "transcript": "your Name is Charlies "
            }
        ],
        "final": true
    }],
    "result_index": 0
};
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.results[0].alternatives.length; i++) {
    if (jsonData.results[0].alternatives[i].confidence > 0) {
        console.log(jsonData.results[0].alternatives[i].transcript);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir,
currently, I am getting below output then how I can read the transcript value:

{
  "results": [
    {
      "keywords_result": {
        "blocked": [
          {
            "normalized_text": "blocked",
            "start_time": 1.1,
            "confidence": 0.64,
            "end_time": 1.68
          }
        ]
      },
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.81,"transcript": "your Name is Charlie"},{ "transcript": "your Name is Charlie and "},{"transcript": "your Name is Charlies"}],"final": true}],"result_index": 0}

Comment: Do you need transcript value of each object within alternatives collection?

Comment: Or tell me the exact condition for which you need transcript value

Comment: In my answer I am retrieving transcript value only if confidence is greater than 0. So you can make changes in that condition

Comment: In my answer I have used exactly same Json object that you referring to. So it should work for you. Please accept and up vote answer if it does.